# awk, grep, sed to extract string based on location in a tab delimited file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a tab delimited file more than 8 million rows and 8 columns; like this:

```
contig17_11 T   C   0.05    TACTACTTGTGGACGAT   TTTTGGCACCCTACGATTAATT  TTTTT   CNCCN
contig10_97 G   A   0.05    GCTCCTGTCGGAAAATAACCCGA GGGGTGTTGATTGTTTTCTT    GGGGG   NNANA
contig10_10 G   A   0.05    GCAAGAGATAGAGCATCGCTC   GGATCCCCAGGACCTGAGAC    GGGGG   AAAAN
```

I need to extract lines where the 4th character (DNA base) is either A or C or G or T at the 7th column, and the 4th character is "N" at the 8th column. Both 7th and 8th columns are 5 letters in length. I tried basic awk grep commands to do this but no results. I tried cat inputfile | awk '$8 ~ /N/' >outfile to practice, bit not what I am looking for.

Comment: Could you format the example data more clearly, so the line breaks are obvious?

Comment: I did not know how, thanks Fredrik

Answer (score 3):

Does this solve your problem?

```
$ awk '/...[ACGT].\t...N.$/' input.txt
contig10_97 G   A   0.05    GCTCCTGTCGGAAAATAACCCGA GGGGTGTTGATTGTTTTCTT    GGGGG   NNANA
```

Same technique applied using sed:

```
$ sed -n '/...[ACGT].\t...N.$/p' input.txt
contig10_97 G   A   0.05    GCTCCTGTCGGAAAATAACCCGA GGGGTGTTGATTGTTTTCTT    GGGGG   NNANA
```

And finaly grep:

```
$ grep -o '^.*...[ACGT].        ...N.$' input.txt
contig10_97 G   A   0.05    GCTCCTGTCGGAAAATAACCCGA GGGGTGTTGATTGTTTTCTT    GGGGG   NNANA
```

here the tab character is inserted using `ctrl-v tab` on the command line.

or using the P switch for grep enabling PCRE (Perl regular expression):

```
$ grep -oP '^.*...[ACGT].\t...N.$' input.txt
contig10_97 G   A   0.05    GCTCCTGTCGGAAAATAACCCGA GGGGTGTTGATTGTTTTCTT    GGGGG   NNANA
```

Comment: Sorry, my sample did not show but the 7th column is not just ACGT, it also has N. So it could be NNNNN, or ANNNN or GTNAA, Basically 5^5 different combinations are possible at both 7th and 8th columns.

Comment: If I understand you correctly that all you need to do is use `awk '/...[ACGTN].\t...N.$/'` instead. If that isn't correct, then I'd suggest you update your question with an example that shows the input and the expected output.

Comment: Fredrik, I run into more problems, The data file in some instances has an extra column, columns.

Comment: Basically, some rows have 8 columns, some 9 and some 10. Like this:                                                                           contig1493_44 T C 0.05 TGAGTACATCGGTCATAACATTAAAACCACTC CCTCTTCAATTTAAACAGCTGTTTGTGTAAAAGT ACTCN NCNNN
contig1493111_424 T C A 0.05 TGAGTACATCGGTCATAACATTAAAACCACTAAC CCTCTTCAATTTAAACAGCTGTTTGTGTAAAACC GGGNA NCNNN
contig1493111_424 T C A G 0.05 TGAGTACATCGGTCATAACATTAAAACCACTAC CCTCTTCAATTTAAACAGCTGTTTGTGTAAAAG TAATG NCNNN

Comment: Post a new question and we'd gladly help you again! Kent's answer is also very good and it works regardless of totall number of columns

Comment: Kent's answer is also very good and it works regardless of totall number of columns

Answer (score 2):

The given example has only 7 columns. 
Any way, you can do it with awk. awk has `substr` function.

```
awk -F'\t' 'substr($7,4,1)~/[ACGT]/ && substr($8,4,1)=="N"' file
```

The one-liner is not tested, but it's pretty straightforward, almost word to word translated your requirement.

Comment: No need to use `-F'\t'` and the example has 8 columns :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, in sed:

```
sed -n -e "s/.*\t...[AGCT].\t...N.$/\0/p" dna.txt
```